# Use separate Log4j for storm in java

Tags: java, log4j, apache-storm

Hi I am using storm in java program and making some storm topology. Now when i use logger for my personal information then those logs are getting stored is /storm/logs along with storm system logs. I know storm also uses log4j. Now i want that my java program should write my logs (as i am using separate log4j) on to other file like /home/mylog.out and storm logs should still be writing in /storm/logs.

I tried to search a lot but got nothing.

Is this possible? and How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is more log4j related than storm.

sure you can use log4j's xml config like this:

```
<appender name="logofmycode" class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender">       
    <param name="File" value="LOG_PATH_OF_YOUR_CODE/log4j.log" />
    <param name="Append" value="true" />    
    <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="10" />    
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">    
        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%p (%c:%L)- %m%n" />    
    </layout>    
</appender>    

<logger name="com.mycode" additivity="false">    
    <priority value ="info"/>      
    <appender-ref ref="logofmycode" />      
</logger>
```

The key is specify an appender to your own package.

Comment: Where do you put that?  Is it part of the topology JAR, part of the storm configuration, somewhere else?  I think that's the difficulty.

Comment: The storm's log4j config file would be the best place to hold this if you can control the file. And this also brings one itch of storm. There is no classload system designed like Servlet. And this brings some problems.

Comment: sorry , if i want to add some logging statements in the b-0 bolt to confirm if i'm getting any non-tick tuples in the execute method. how can i do that ?